# How do I prove $\operatorname{rank}(ABC)\geq \operatorname{rank}(AB)+\operatorname{rank}(BC)-\operatorname{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Actually, I've already seen the solution, but I still don't understand.
The solution used partitioned matrices.
Plus, somebody teach me how to put mathematical symbols by mobile..

How do I prove $\operatorname{rank}(ABC)\geq \operatorname{rank}(AB)+\operatorname{rank}(BC)-\operatorname{rank}(B)$

Comment: Math symbols by mobile is done exactly the same way as math symbols otherwise on this site: by following the procedure outlined [on this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Perhaps you could include the solution so that people can help with that.

Comment: You mention partitioned matrices in the solution, does $ABC$ refer to the product of $A$, $B$, and $C$ or the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A&B&C\end{bmatrix}$?